# Angular | Change md-select option using setValue

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to set a select option but can't seem to get it working. Running `this.eventForm.controls.venue.setValue(event.venue.name);` changes the value of `venue`, to whatever `event.venue.name` is, but the select option doesn't change.

component.ts

```
const eventObject = this.db.object(`/events/${eventId}`);
    console.log(eventObject);

    this.existingEvent = eventObject
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe((event: Object) => this.reForm(event),
      (error: any) => { console.log(error) }
      );

  reForm(event): void {

    if (this.eventForm) {
      this.eventForm.reset();
    }

    console.log(this.eventForm.controls.venue);

    this.eventForm.controls.venue.setValue(event.venue.name);

    this.eventForm.patchValue({
      category: event.category,
      date: event.date,
      // venue: event.venue.name,
      description: event.description,
      name: event.name,
    })
  }
```

component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="eventForm">

    <md-select class="example-full-width" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Venue"
                (change)="venueProcess($event)">
                <md-option *ngFor="let venue of venues | async" [value]="venue.$key">
                  {{ venue.name }}
                </md-option>
              </md-select>
</form>
```

*** Edit. Image after setting value

[image]

Comment: are you using template-driven form or reactive (aka. model-driven) form?

Comment: The form is reactive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
this.eventForm.controls.venue.setValue(event.venue.$key);
```

And in HTML template, add `formControlName` to bind everything up:

```
<md-select formControlName="venue" class="example-full-width" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Venue" (change)="venueProcess($event)">
   <md-option *ngFor="let venue of venues | async" [value]="venue.$key">
      {{ venue.name }}
   </md-option>
</md-select>
```

You are using `venue.name` as display text, and `venue.$key` as option value. You should set the form control value to match the option value, not option display text.

Comment: Makes sense ... but it doesn't work. I tried hard coding one of the option keys this.eventForm.controls.venue.setValue('-KtXsBCzW8dkvfc_ahyg‌​'); but it didn't change. The select form's value changes. I did a console .log of console.log(this.eventForm.controls); and the venue's value changes. See the image in my post. But the `md-select` doesn't change.

Comment: That might be it. I will check and let you know. Thank you.

Comment: yup. That was it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add ngModel in select option , 
so i hope below should work for you ( change in HTML only )

```
<form [formGroup]="eventForm">

<md-select class="example-full-width" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" placeholder="Venue" [(ngModel)]="event.venue.name"
            (change)="venueProcess($event)">
            <md-option *ngFor="let venue of venues | async" [value]="venue.$key">
              {{ venue.name }}
            </md-option>
          </md-select>
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I don't have a property event ... so I can't get `event.venue.name`. What I tried to do is set a property `v` like this: `this.v = event.venue.name` and use it in the ngModel tag like so: `[(ngModel)]="v"` ... but it gave this error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasValue' of undefined`

Comment: you need to initialise "v"